# how to know if hstore datatype have particular key?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has a column with data type `hstore` and now I want to know which rows don't have a particular key in it. The query I tried is:

```
select * from user_offer where not outputs ? 'target_term' and rule_id = 221 limit 10
```

Note outputs is `hstore` column and `target_term` is key.

Answer (score 0):

If the key target_term does not exist, outputs -> 'target_term' returns NULL, so you can try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM user_offer WHERE (outputs -> 'target_term'::TEXT) IS NULL AND rule_id = 221 LIMIT 10;
```

This select the rows where the column outputs does not have the key target_term.

See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/hstore.html

Comment: didn't worked.. well because as I said 'outputs' is column name and  column datatype is  hstore

Comment: right, if 'outputs' is a hstore column, the query should work. Can you post the error message? Or, what do you mean exactly with "didn't work"?

Comment: ERROR: operator dose not exist: public_extensions.hstore -> unknown HINT: no operator matches the given name and argument types. you might need to add explicit type casts

Comment: Probably are you using a key which is not a text/varchar. Try casting to text with `outputs -> 'target_term'::TEXT` (I updated my answer, see above )